# How to delete a database file (.dbf) from Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle-10g, dbf

I need help deleting a DB file from Oracle. I suppose I should use the `DROP` command, but I cannot make it work.

I tried dropping all the users, except system user, from dba_users, hoping that this will result in getting rid of the databases, but I find that some .dbf file is still there.

Can someone give me an example for dropping .dbf file?

Comment: it depends on a lot of things, such as what storage model you use. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database files in Oracle typically represent a table space, so you'll need to use the DROP TABLESPACE command.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**  Do not try to delete these files outside of Oracle, or else Oracle might not start at all.

An example could be:

- `DROP TABLESPACE tablespace_name;`

You shouldn't need to drop users or any other objects for this to work (if there are any dependencies, Oracle will let you know when you attempt to drop the table space).

Answer (score -1):

ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\ORADATA\UKOUG\DATAFILE\O1_MF_USERS_35HCKNFO_.DBF'
OFFLINE DROP;

Comment: You MUST make your answer valid by restating the question, and applying instructions on what to do with this line of code. In the meantime, sorry, but I had to flag your post.